# .NET Core docker - linux container. Find specific file of my built-project

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers

I am using .NET Core with docker that is Linux container type (build on Windows 10).

I run my program for testing in Windows, and for production in Linux.

I have a text file: **"sample.txt"** in the docker.

**I want to find the exact location of the text file in the docker.**

I built and ran the docker using "docker-compose build" and "docker-compose up" respectively.

Keep it running (by some loop in my code), and open another command line prompt, and run:

```
docker exec -t -i <DOCKER_ID> /bin/sh
```

and after that run:

```
ls /
```

The result is:

> bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint.sh  etc  home  lib  lib64  media 
>   mnt  opt  plugins  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

running the command:

```
find . -print | grep -i 'sample.txt'
```

returns the output:

```
find: ‘./proc/1/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/105/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/172/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/280/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/321/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/322/map_files’: Permission denied
```

How can I find the exact location in the docker for the file: **"sample.txt"**?

(That can be any file).

**Also - Can I run executable linux file that is outside the docker from the docker itself?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path can be seen when building the docker image (when running : 'run dotnet publish ...' or 'run dotnet build ...'

In docker file just put a "COPY" command to the linux path.

Generaly the path is (when compiling to /app):

> /app/runtimes/linux-x64/native

The relevant lines in DockerFile:

```
...
RUN dotnet publish MyProj.csproj --no-cache -c Release -o /app
...
COPY MyProj/Objects/MyLib/Linux /app/runtimes/linux-x64/native
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can use the command:

```
find / -name sample.txt
```

This command will search all the sample.txt if it is located in the file system.

For your second question, I would use a volume that maps to a specific folder inside your host machine to a folder inside the docker container , and afterward you can easily go to the location in the docker container and run it.